# TRying to replicate a cool dropdown content

Tags: jquery, css, html, drop-down-menu

I just saw this page : http://www.gdconf.com/expo/exhibitorlist.html

It has a cool drop down details when you select exhibitor.

I want to use this for my website, I won't be using dynamic data for it. I'm trying to figure out the what the method is called or if there are tutorials for it. I looked in the source code but it's in an iframe so I can't see what it's doing behind the scenes.

```
 <!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="Main Column" -->
    <iframe src="http://gdc2012.b2b-match.com/_tools/gdc2012_exhibitors/" scrolling="no" framebo     rder=0 width=740 height=20000></iframe> 
 <!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
```

Any pointers on where to start would be very helpful, thanks. Michael

Comment: jQuery [slideDown()](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/) ?

Comment: They are using a slidetoggle.you can see here for code.it is simple.http://gdc2012.b2b-match.com/_tools/gdc2012_exhibitors/javascript.js

Comment: Paste the iframes URL into your browser and view source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for an accordion plugin.

It might be overkill for what you're after but you could think about using the jQuery UI plugin - http://jqueryui.com/download

It's a pretty handy collection of components, animations and other handy things that make websites awesome.

It's got accordion's built in to it - http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/

**HINT:** When you download it you can select what parts of it you want to install to keep file size down.

Answer (score 1):

That's the accordion buttons effect built with jquery (i think that's what you're talking about).

tutorials and code here:

[JQuery UI Site](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/)

Answer (score 1):

example
http://jsfiddle.net/amkrtchyan/jUraw/317/